# I want to know how to use pyqt5 to load the created widget at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Sorry. I will modify the contents. I would like to load a widget inside def test by pressing Qbutton. Can not you use QStackedWidget to load the widget's configured functions? I've compiled the class and called it, but only a = QLineEdit ('Qline', self). I wonder what should be done to switch widgets.

You can also create a table like html using pyqt5.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked = QStackedWidget(self)

        self.FirstpUI() 

    def FirstpUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton('test1', self)
        self.btn1.move(50,50)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_click)

    def test(self):
        a = QLineEdit('Qline', self)
        b = QLineEdit('Qline2', self)
        c = QPushButton('button', self)

        a.move(0, 0)
        b.move(100, 0)
        c.move(50,50)

        c.clicked.connect(self.btn2_click)

    def btn1_click(self):
        self.btn1.deleteLater()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.test())

        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex()+1)

    def btn2_click(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self,'hello','hello2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fream = MainWindow()
    fream.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: explain yourself better, what is your problem? Where have you defined `btn2_click`? Do you think that `self.test()` is a widget: `self.stacked.addWidget(self.test())`?

Comment: I thought I could use `self.stacked.addWidget ()` to construct the widget and load it as a function.

Comment: no, that is not correct, addWidget() is used to add a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I don't know what you real want,because I know that little, I think You can use QtDesigner,it's very useful